# Index optimization for IN, BETWEEN, ORDER BY and LIMIT query

Tags: mysql, database-design, index, performance, optimization, query-performance

**Brief Background** of issue

We have a aggregate table to store activities and have currently 6.6 Million rows and we need create listing from this table.

This activity listing have features of **filtering** as well as **sorting** on different different columns.

Data in this table Meaning Activities count is increasing at 1 million/month rate.

We are using MySQL with version 5.6

**Table structure** is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `filter` (
  `source_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `metrics_1` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `metrics_2` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `metrics_3` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `posted_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`source_id`,`type`,`entity_id`),
  KEY `indx_posted_on` (`posted_on`,`source_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Primary Key** for this table is

```
PRIMARY KEY (`source_id`,`type`,`entity_id`)
```

**Query** we are using to retrieve list of activities is

```
SELECT
    filter.`entity_id`
FROM filter AS filter
LEFT JOIN act_deleted AS act_deleted ON act_deleted.entity_id = filter.entity_id
WHERE
    filter.source IN(211,493)
    AND filter.`type` = 1
    AND filter.posted_on BETWEEN '2015-01-29 00:00:00' AND '2016-08-12 23:59:59'
    AND filter.metrics_1 BETWEEN 0 AND 9999999999
    AND act_deleted.entity_id IS NULL
ORDER BY filter.`posted_on` DESC 
LIMIT 5000, 50;
```

**NOTE**
`act_deleted` contains deleted rows. we do not want to show deleted rows to perticular user.

`type`, `metrics_1`, `metrics_2` condition is dynamic, if user select this filter, it will be there in `WHERE` part.

**INDEX created for this query is**

I read about indexes and created this index for the above query as we have sorting on `posted_on` for this query.

```
`indx_posted_on` (`posted_on`)
```

**Execution** Plan
[image]

**Issues we facing are as follows**

1) First time query execution time is about `28 seconds` even with index.

**Time** Taken

[image]

**NOTE** consecutive query execution time is `1 second` with same indexes. I read mysql buffers the table data and so consecutive query execution is faster.

2) There can be high (30 sources max) in `IN` part of the query and when i do that, applied indexes gets change in query execution plan and execution time increases to about `15 seconds`. should be under `2 seconds`.

**Output** of `Explain` for this scenario as follows
[image]

**Time Taken**

[image]

Solution can be for this issue is to use `FORCE INDEX`. **is it okay if i use force index ?**

3) **Most important** issue is i need to add sorting on `metrics_1`, `metrics_2` field also. 
**do i need to create seperate indexes for that ?**
Concern is if i make seperate indexes for each scenario it increases size of table and it results in deadlock while data insertion. (Currently table is about 10 GB in size)

**UPDATE**
Most simple query would be (without any filter by user)

```
SELECT
    filter.*
FROM `filters` AS filter
LEFT JOIN act_deleted AS act_deleted ON (act_deleted.entity_id = filter.entity_id AND act_deleted.user_id = 1)
WHERE
    filter.source_id IN (211,493,527,505,554,465,561,565,529,537,504,485,542,590,488,533,468,545,477,547,569,521,513,461,663) AND
    (filter.posted_on BETWEEN '2015-07-29 00:00:00' AND '2016-08-12 23:59:59') AND
    act_deleted.entity_id IS NULL
ORDER BY filter.`posted_on` DESC / ORDER BY filter.`metrics_1` DESC / ORDER BY filter.`metrics_2` DESC
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

**UPDATE**

When i add more indexes, it increases table size (currently about 10 GB TOTAL size where 2 GB of data and 8 GB index size)) and i'm getting dead lock in update part in one same query.

When i tried to update `metrics_1` in batch, it results in dead lock few times.
Is it because of MORE INDEXES or can be some other reason ?

Please Let me know if any extra information required.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The IN operator is very inefficient. If you have a large number of items for this, you should put them in a temporary table and then join against that table.

Comment: I'm already creating temporary table for this entities and using JOIN to get other data. is it good to create two temporary tables ? one for sources and then one for entities ?

Comment: why would it matter?

Comment: Ideally it should not matter. i can have maximum 30 values in `IN` part and that part is mandatory for each query on this table. is it good to create temporary table solution as compare to use of `IN` operator ?

Comment: Yes it is. I already said that.

Comment: (2nd UPDATE):  2GB vs 8GB is unreasonable; please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: (2nd UPDATE):  How were you updating `metrics_1`?  There may be another way to do that.

Comment: If you are always testing for "not being deleted", consider actually deleting the rows (in order to avoid that test).  Note:  You could copy the "deleted" records to another table if you need to keep them and use `UNION ALL` when you need to see them.

Answer (score 1):

Shrinking the table size will help performance:

- Don't use `BIGINT` unless you expect to need more than 4 billion ids; `INT UNSIGNED` takes half the space.
- Don't use `INT` (4 bytes) for low-cardinality flags/types/levels(?)/etc.  `ENUM` or `TINYINT UNSIGNED` is only 1 byte.

Write a little more code to avoid useless parts to the `WHERE`, such as `AND filter.metrcs_1 BETWEEN 0 AND 9999999999`.

Pagination via `OFFSET` (`LIMIT 5000, 50`) is problematic.  See [*my blog*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/)

Don't `USE INDEX` or `FORCE INDEX`; it may help today, but it is likely to hurt tomorrow.

It is rarely useful to *start* with a column that will be used in a 'range':  KEY `indx_posted_on` (`posted_on`,`source_id`)

For *that* query: `INDEX(type, source_id, posted_on),`INDEX(type, posted_on)`.  The first of those covers the case where you have only one`source_id`.  (Does such happen?).  The second one is better than`INDEX(posted_on)`.

More on [*optimal indexes*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/)  To summarize:  `=`s first, optionally `IN`s, and one range last.  But the `IN` keeps the `ORDER BY` from being consumed.

Also, be sure that `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is about 70% of *available* RAM; this may help cut back on I/O.

**UPDATE** (based on OP's UPDATE):

```
INDEX(source_id, posted_on) -- IN + range -- should help with WHERE
INDEX(posted_on) -- part of WHERE, plus may consume ORDER BY
```

The Optimizer will pick between the two.

If `AND metrics_1 BETWEEN...` is added in, the performance will be worse.  So, keep it out of the query if the user does not need it.

Since you have a large set of possible queries, I recommend building a few indexes:

```
INDEX(posted_on) -- to handle the ORDER BY, in case nothing else works well
INDEX(const, posted_on) -- to partially handle WHERE, plus ORDER BY
INDEX(const, range) -- a few 2-column indexes;
          first is something used with '=', second is BETWEEN (or other range)
INDEX(in, range) -- a few more 2-column indexes;
          first is something used with 'IN', second is a range
```

Aim for no more than 10 total.  Watch what users usually ask about as a guide to which 'const'/'in'/'range' columns to index.  And/or look at what queries are "too" slow.

Don't say `filter.*` unless you really need all the columns.  In particular, if all `TEXT` columns can be omitted, there *may* be a performance gain in how temp tables are handled.

For large tables with text columns, this "lazy eval" *may* help performance:

```
SELECT filter.*
    FROM (
        SELECT primary-key-fields-of-filter
                  rest-of-existing-SELECT
                  order-by-limit
         ) x
    JOIN filter USING(primary-key-fields-of-filter)
    ORDER BY repeat-the-order-by-but-not-limit
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
Have changed all field types as you suggested. 
Regarding indexes, i do not have anything constant in `WHERE`part. `type` field is also optional. so it is good to add `type` field in indexes even if its not compulsory in query ?

Comment: No, there will always high number in IN part for source_id. (for other individual pages, source_id will be constant for some other queries)

Comment: Concern is if i make seperate indexes for each scenario it increases size of table and it results in deadlock while data insert/update operation. (Currently table is about 10 GB in size)
My concern is valid ?

Comment: Indexes columns are used left to right.  So if the query does not say `type=constant`, `INDEX(type, ...)` is useless.